# NgRx Store with selector called twice

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have simple store with selector

```
export const efficiency = createSelector(
    state => ({ ...state.dashboard}),
    dashboard => dashboard.efficiency
);
```

And Store Subscription

```
this.store
  .pipe(
    select(efficiency )
  )
  .subscribe(state => {console.log(state)})
```

Due to some reason state subscription invoking **twice**.
Also, Is their a way to restrict subscription invocation when selector initializes?

Comment: What do you mean selector is called twice? It will called as many times as State is updated, since it is an Observable.

Comment: while using store subscription is necessary to unsubscribe it, otherwise every time subscription instantiated, those many time subscription callback invoked.

In my case on component init, i was subscribing the store and since navigation to same component was happening multiple time, the subscription list was increasing, resulting in the invocation of subscription callback multiple times for single dispatch call.

Comment: Oh I see, now I get what you mean by twice. Did you solve problem?

Comment: yup..problem solved

Comment: Mind sharing your solution?

Comment: I'm interested by your solution :)

Comment: Unsubscribing the observables on component destroy didn't solve the issue in my case.